# Extra space underneath navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm currently trying to make a website, and I managed to create a navigation bar. However, there is a weird "extra" space between my navigation bar. It was working fine at first but after I referenced a JQuery. However, I doubt the JQuery is the one that caused the problem as the site looks the same even after I took it out. [Here's a screenshot of the problem. I'm trying to get rid of the circled part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AZzO.png)

My HTML code:

```
        <div id="nav">                                                                  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <nav>                                                                   
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="selected" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>                          <!-- Link to about page -->
                    <li class="drop">
                        <a href="games.html" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
                        <div class="drop-content">
                            <a href="rfg.html">Red Faction: Guerrilla</a>       <!-- Contains links to the respective pages -->
                            <a href="wots3.html">Way of the Samurai 3</a>
                            <a href="singularity.html">Singularity</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="external.html">External Store</a></li>                 <!-- Link to external site -->
                    <li><a href="video.html">Videos</a></li>                            <!-- Contains links to Youtube -->
                    <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>                       <!--Feedback form-->
```

And here's the stylesheet:

```
#nav nav{                                   /* Navigation bar*/
padding-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5% }

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
background-color: #1C86EE;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block }

#nav li {
float: left;
width: 14% }

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 15%;
padding-right: 15%;
text-decoration: none }

.selected {
background-color: #6CCC0A;
padding-right: 25% }

li a:hover, .drop:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #BFA810 }

a {
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em }

li.drop {
display: inline-block }

.drop-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #970707;
min-width: 14%;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #000000;
z-index: 100 }

.drop-content a {
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 15px 20px;
display: block;
text-align: left }

.drop-content a:hover {
background-color: #02BBC4 }

.drop:hover .drop-content {
display: block;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute }                                /*End of navigation*/

* {                                     /* index style */
box-sizing:border-box
}
body {
font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
margin:0
}
.slideshow-fade {
display:none
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow {
 max-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}
.slideshow img {
opacity: 0.7
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 padding: 1em;
 margin-top: -1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 padding: 1% 2%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 2%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.number {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 1em;
 width: 4%;
 margin: 0 2px;
 background-color: #bbbbbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
 background-color: #717171;
 }

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width : 720px ){
.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
.slideshow-fade a {
color: #FFFFFF
}
.slideshow-fade a:visited {
color: #5115D0
}                                               /*End of style for index*/
footer {                                    /*Footer*/
background: #000000;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding-top: 2%;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer p {
font-family: arial, calibri, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}                               /*End of footer*/
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the jsfiddle file to make it more convenient to see the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/8xutoea5/

Edit: Added more CSS codes.
Edit: I solved the problem. Thanks everyone for taking the time to solve this problem.

Comment: Piece of advice, paste your code on a jsfiddle when asking something like this. If we can inspect the problem it will be much faster to help you and more people will try.

Comment: you do not have closing UL or you just did not post it here? seems to be most important part to leave out... do you have more items in UL?

Comment: I have a closing ul and div, but I forgot to post it here. @MarkE

Comment: @NawedKhan Sorry, I'm still new to this. I don't know how to use jsfiddle

Comment: it seems to be working fine. here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73rj6942/

Comment: @NawedKhan There's still a blue space underneath it

Comment: that is because in jsfiddle the output screen is very narrow and your text is wrapping into multiple lines. if you see in full screen there is no space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you have your `ul` as `inline-block`, that will cause some space after elements. Also you have float on your `li` without a clearfix on nav.

You can solve this in various ways, here is one where you can use `display: flex;` and remove the `float: left;` on `li`. This is a pretty solid base you can build on with changing the `justify-content` property. You can find a awesome guide to flexbox over at [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**UPDATE**
I made some updates to the fiddle to solve the problem. Please note the code on top, also I made some other changes. Write if there is something unclear

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73rj6942/2/)

```
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1C86EE;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#nav li {
  width: 14%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and it works. May I ask what display: flex and justify-content: space-between does?

Comment: @Noob I updated my answer with link to info about flexbox :)

Comment: Thank you once again for the solution.

Comment: @MarkE there is no space below the green home selection. I guess that was what the op wanted to solve. Also this example points out other flaws in the css like float without clearfix.

Comment: @Dejan.S I still see that space below unless I make the render screen bigger. Although if op is happy with it, then nvm.

Comment: I just realised that the problem was only halfway solved. It still has the blue screen when I zoom out. If it's impossible to solve the problem fully, then I guess I'll just leave it as that and hope no one zooms out while looking at my site.

Comment: @Noob this menu has more issues then just that. I can point out css that could be better. Also you don't mention for what breakpoint you want this menu to go to? do you mean zoom in?

Comment: The main point of the navigation bar was for it to be responsive so that when the user zooms in or out, it will resize accordingly. I haven't gotten around to the responsive part yet though as I saw the problem while trying to implement responsiveness. Also, I would very much appreciate it if you could point out the CSS that could be better.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to edit your jsfiddle. It works now. What I do not understand is where the problem came from.

Comment: @Noob the problem left was (as other mentioned) the wrap of the word. What you needed to do was to make the li take 100% of the height of the nav and align the text to center when it broke to two rows, if that makes sense? I can point out the places I changed if you like? I strongly recommend you to read on flex.

Comment: I see. I understand now. Thanks for the clarification. I will read up more on flex.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a margin somewhere else in your CSS, not provided here, that is causing the issue. You could try setting `margin-bottom:0;` a few places to see if that solves it.

```
#nav nav ul li {                                 
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


#nav nav ul li a {                                 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Or provide the rest of your style sheet.

Comment: Removing it only makes the photo closer to the nav bar. The space is still there. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: the space appears inside the blue area defined by UL. So removing outside (bottom) margin from the whole nav element will not help.

Comment: There must be something else in your CSS causing the problem that wasn't included in your code. Using what you posted here works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/LpgdoqcL/

Comment: @Wellspring There's still a blue space under the green box. What I wanted to make was a green box only without the extra blue space under it.

Comment: If you're seeing bluespace in the JS Fiddle, it is b/c the width of the nav bar causes "External Store" to break and display on two lines. If you expand the result area in JS Fiddle, it shows the nav bar without the blue space under it. This is unlike the photo you provided, which has "External Store" on one line and the blue space.

Comment: @Wellspring I see now, thanks for the answer. However, on my site, it still has the blue space underneath. Any ideas as to how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more of your CSS code? There must be something else that is overriding the the CSS you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the section "External Store", it's too long and it wraps. You can make it shorter or force a "no-wrap".
With the css property `white-space` with the value `nowrap`.
You have no classes on your internal tags so I would suggest add a class to the `a` tags and add the rule to it.

```
a.listLink{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or you can just add a style attribute to that specific tag but I don't find that solution cool enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I force a "no-wrap"?

Comment: Thanks for the example on how to force a "no-wrap". I tried it but it didn't work. However, I think this might come in handy for me.

Comment: Weird, it worked for me on the jsfiddle. I just changed `<a href="external.html">External Store</a>` for `<a href="external.html" style="white-space: nowrap;" >External Store</a>` to test it.

Comment: Just found a typo on the example, sorry.

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't work on my main site.

Comment: I get what you mean @MarkE with the `nowrap`, although this introduces another issue with responsive that the menus go into each other on small screens. There are more issues with this navigation then just that "space". Like it needs some kind of breakpoint when to act differently.

Comment: @Dejan.S I know it overlaps and that's also a problem he would need to solve. I guess I just gave an oversimplified answer. I saw the problem was wrapping so I told how to prevent it.